# take audio from mp4 video using ffmpeg

Tags: go, audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use the go wrapper over ffmpeg https://github.com/u2takey/ffmpeg-go

to take audio from an mp4 video. I don't want to create extra local files, but I can't pass the input otherwise.

I transfer the created file and return the audio to io.Reader(`audio` var):

```
    telegramFile, err := r.bot.GetFile(&msg.VideoNote.File)
    if err != nil {
        // handling error
    }
    fileBytes, err := io.ReadAll(telegramFile)
    if err != nil {
        // handling error
    }

    inputFile := fmt.Sprintf("%s.mp4", msg.VideoNote.File.FileID)
    err = ioutil.WriteFile(inputFile, fileBytes, 0o600)
    if err != nil {
        // handling error
    }

    audio := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    err = ffmpeg.Input(
        inputFile,
    ).
        Output("pipe:1", ffmpeg.KwArgs{"format": "wav"}).WithOutput(audio).Run()
    if err != nil {
        // handling error
    }
```

I am sending io.Reader(`telegramFile` var) and get io.Reader(`audio` var):

```
    telegramFile, err := r.bot.GetFile(&msg.VideoNote.File)
    if err != nil {
        // handling error
    }

    audio := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    err = ffmpeg.Input(
        "pipe:0", ffmpeg.KwArgs{"format": "mp4"},
    ).
        Output("pipe:1", ffmpeg.KwArgs{"format": "wav"}).WithInput(telegramFile).WithOutput(audio).Run()
    if err != nil {
        // handling error
    }
```

the first code works, but I need the second one. The conversion is performed, but the audio is invalid. Too few bytes.

here is an example of using input -> output https://github.com/u2takey/ffmpeg-go/blob/8af5c3849807dcda756406a7b2b3631a5c90d53b/ffmpeg_test.go#L330